# How to act on an object depending on the instanceof?

Tags: java, oop, gwt

I have a `GWT` `Canvas` that is drawing several `Shapes`, like (I'm not sure if I'm going for extension or implementation of an interface):

```
Rectangle extends/implements Shape;
Ellipse extends/implements Shape;
```

For every `Shape` I want to show an own context menu, ie set a context menu widget into a popup like:

```
if (shape instanceof Rectangle) {
  Widget contextmenu = new RectangleContextMenu();
} else if (shape instanceof Ellipse) {
  Widget contextmenu = new EllipseContextMenu();
}
popup.setWidget(contextmenu);
popup.show();
```

It should not matter that I'm using GWT here as this might be a general design question:

How can I act on my Shape objects and always call the action that should belong to that instance?

Eg other operations could be:

- `draw()`: ob course a ellipse is drawn differently than an rectangle
- `rotate()`: an ellipse might follow different rotation rules
- `delete()`: I could later imagine that deletion of `Ellipse` objects should follow different rules than deletion of `Rectangles` (as they will later on represent certain objects in my app).

As I'm still in the design: what could you suggest to that I can later have a List where I just can execute things like `shape.draw()` or `delete(shape)` and the appropriate methods will be called automatically?

I could achieve this by `Interface Shape` here:

```
interface Shape {
   abstract draw();
   abstract delete(Shape);
   abstract rotate();
}
```

, which would have the drawback that I have to copy all the code from `draw()` logic to all my `Shape` classes that `implement` this interface, even if they are only slightly different, or maybe they do not differ at all.

Could there be a better approach?

Comment: Interface, then abstract class with default / common functionality, and concrete classes extending abstract class.

Comment: Work out which bits of the method would differ and `abstract` those. Implement the core functionality in an `abstract Shape` so that you can override if required.

Comment: In addition to implementation inheritance, you can also share code by object composition or static helper methods. No need to copy/paste code.

Comment: For the ContextMenu part of the question, have an interface `HasContextMenu` with a method `Widget getContextMenu()` that your Shapes can implement to get rid of the instanceof block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `interface` that defines what a `Shape` must do - i.e. defines a contract.

Create an `abstract class` that defines core functionality that is repeated in all `Shape` instances.

Maybe create more `abstract class`es that define more specific functionality that would be repeated, say, for all quadrilaterals.

Finally create concrete shapes that extend the relevant base class:

```
interface Shape {

    void draw();

    void delete();

    void rotate();
}

abstract class BaseShape implements Shape {

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        //do generic stuff
        //call specific method
        specificDrawStuff();
        //do more generic stuff
    }

    abstract void specificDrawStuff();

    @Override
    public void rotate() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void delete() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}

class Square extends BaseShape {

    @Override
    void specificDrawStuff() {
        //specfic stuff here
    }
}
```

This way you can abstract away anything that is common, but you can also `implement Shape` directly if you need to.